# expected primary-expression before ">" in g++ but not in microsoft compiler

Tags: c++, templates

This code fails to compile on g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, with this error

```
test.cpp: In function ‘T mul(V&, V&)’:
test.cpp:38:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
test.cpp:38:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
test.cpp:38:53: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
test.cpp:38:55: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

but it compiles and executes correctly on Microsoft C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for x64

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

template <class T>
class SM
{
public:
    T value;
};

template <class T>
class SC : public SM<T>
{
};

class PSSM {

public:
    template <class T>
    T & getSC() { return sc; }

private:
    SC<double> sc;
};

class USSM {

public:
    template <class T>
    T & getSC() { return sc; }

private:
    SC<std::complex<double> > sc;
};

template <class T, class V>
T mul( V & G, V & S) {
    return (G.getSC<SC<T> >().value * S.getSC<SC<T> >().value); // error is here
}


int main() {
    PSSM p;
    PSSM q;
    p.getSC<SC<double> >().value = 5; 
    q.getSC<SC<double> >().value = 3; 

    std::cout << mul<double>(p,q);

}
```

I don't understand where the problem is. Can anyone understand how to work around it, or explain the nature of the problem in g++?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem is syntactic. You should use the `template` disambiguator in this case, so that your invocation of a member function template will be correctly parsed:

```
return (G.template getSC<SC<T> >().value * S.template getSC<SC<T> >().value);
//        ^^^^^^^^^                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

This disambiguator helps the compiler recognizing that what follows `G.` is a *member template specialization* and not, for instance, a data member called `getSC` followed by a `<` (less than).

The Standard reference for the `template` disambiguator is Paragraph 14.2/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a postfix-expression or after a *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and the object expression of the *postfix-expression* is type-dependent or the *nested-name-specifier* in the qualified-id refers to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), **the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.**[ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct X {
> template<std::size_t> X* alloc();
> template<std::size_t> static X* adjust();
> };
> template<class T> void f(T* p) {
> T* p1 = p->alloc<200>(); // ill-formed: < means less than
> T* p2 = p->template alloc<200>(); // OK: < starts template argument list
> T::adjust<100>(); // ill-formed: < means less than
> T::template adjust<100>(); // OK: < starts template argument list
> }
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

Comment: but why isn't it correctly parsed to begin with ? where does the ambiguity arise?

Comment: Without the 'template' keyword there some compilers confuse the type parameter list with the less-than operator.

Comment: Ugliest. Disambiguator. Ever.

Comment: @mfontanini: I'm afraid I have to agree

Comment: worse is if you have to mix them: typename T.template member<U>::type

Comment: This is the craziest thing we've ever seen, we are three here and nobody ever thought anything like that to be even possible. In two days I'm going to award you 500.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you know this? It's something so obscure even to find out that I can't see how a human can understand what's going on.

Comment: @StefanoBorini: I don't remember where I've met this first, but I believe it must have been in the book "C++ Templates - The Complete Guide" - but I can't tell for sure. Then it happened to me a couple of times while programming and I also had that WTF feeling, so it was easy to keep that in mind.