# "template" disambiguator is c++11. Any chance for VS2008 compiler?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2008, g++

A few weeks ago [I posted this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572415/expected-primary-expression-before-in-g-but-not-in-microsoft-compiler) about a weird error message. The culprit was incorrect parsing of the < token, a problem solved through the use of the "template" disambiguator keyword.

We found an unexpected ugly surprise though. The template disambiguator is c++11, but we need to support VS2008, and it does not support it. So we basically went from something that compiles on windows but not on linux, to something that compiles on linux but not on windows.

Do you have any idea how to solve? Specifically

- is there a magic option in the windows compiler to enable this c++11 construct, or
- there's an alternative way within the old c++ standard to solve that ambiguity that is also cross compiler, or
- if we need to use preprocessor, what are the preprocessor constants (if any) to distinguish the two compilers (gcc is the other one)

Comment: `. template` isn't a C++11 construct.

Comment: `.template` to disambiguate is not specific to C++ 11 . see http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/194/ and http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html section 6,

Comment: Without the the code and error message it is not possible to tell what the problem is.

Comment: @mark The problem is that the proposed solution does not work with VS2008.

Answer (score 8):

The template disabiguator has been part of C++ since C++98.  It was introduced when two phase lookup was introduced, along with `typename`.

Comment: Of course, Visual Studio would have to *support* two-phase lookup for that to matter...

Comment: why is it not recognized by VS2008 compiler then ?

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course.  A lot of posters here propose C++11 solutions at times, but many users are stuck with VC++, which arguably still doesn't support C++98, much less anything newer.  With my tongue firmly in my cheek, I would say that if you're using VC++, you can't use anything newer than the ARM (not yet standard C++ version 1990).

Comment: @StefanoBorini Because VS2008 still implements C++ as defined in the ARM (1990, I think); it still doesn't implement C++98, much less C++03 or C++11.  Basically, if portability (to newer compilers, or to other systems) is an issue, and you must support VC++, you can't even use templates, much less more recent features.  (Actually, of course, it _is_ possible to write template code which works with both models.  But you do have to keep it simple.  If you need the `template` disabiguator, your use is too complicated.)